# How to recreate Windows Live Mail filter rules in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter, windows-live-mail

I have some filters in Windows Live Mail that I'm trying to port to thunderbird without success. It seems Thunderbird filter is very limited. Here is an ex of a filter i'm trying to recreate:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
Where the From line contains 'res_inbc@tam.com.br' or 'interativo@tam.com.br' or 'Programa TAM Fidelidade' 
    and Where the message body contains 'esteja visualizando' and 'por ser cadastrado no Programa TAM Fidelidade' 
Move it to the Deleted items folder 
    and Stop processing more rules
```

In Thunderbird I can´t combine a list of "or"s with some "and"s, because it only allows you to select "message matches ALL of the criteria below" or "ANY of the below". Am I missing something or it really is very limited?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [FiltaQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/) extension.  Seems to support some complex filtering options.

Comment: I have tried it but it seems it only support regular expressions (which I'm not used to), not boolean expressions (AND, OR, ...)